Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'
Recently I switched to pnpm from npm. My Dockerfile built fine until I modified it to make sure it works with pnpm:
FROM node:22.1.0 AS base

ENV PNPM_HOME="/pnpm"
ENV PATH="$PNPM_HOME:$PATH"
RUN corepack enable

FROM base as build

WORKDIR /usr/src/root

COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml nx.json tsconfig.base.json ./
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=pnpm,target=/pnpm/store pnpm install
RUN pnpm install -g nx
COPY ./ /usr/src/root

ENV NX_DAEMON=false
RUN nx run user:build

FROM nginx:1.25.5 AS runtime
COPY --from=build /usr/src/root/dist/apps/user/browser /usr/share/nginx/html/user

I get an error:
ERROR [build 6/7] RUN nx run user:build 

NX   Unable to resolve @angular-devkit/build-angular:application.

Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'
Require stack:
 - /pnpm/global/5/.pnpm/nx@19.3.0/node_modules/nx/src/utils/package-json.js
<...>

Running pnpm install and then nx run user:build locally works fine. Not sure what I am misconfiguring here.
My package.json already contains angular-devkit/build-angular:
 "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "18.0.3",


Somewhy .Dockerignore file was not picked up, I had to rename it to .dockerignore. It used to work before when I was using npm, not sure if anything changed with recent updates.
